# HTTP2 Server send FIN/ACK and then RST without tremendous traffic

Tags: tcp, jersey, http2

I am using Jersey on HTTP2. When traffic goes to a little high then exception raised. And I got the pcap found server send FIN/ACK without receiving FIN. I am not sure it is a single FIN to close the connection from the server side. Or single FIN combined ACK to previous packets. It looks the latter because the client didn't send FIN. So the question is why the server send FIN under only small traffic. And I found the rece_q and send_q is very low. CPU usage is not so high. I have already tuned some TCP parameters and result is the same. This behavior is unstable, sometime it is ok, sometime not ok. when I add more requests(with same TPS) then not ok. It looks server finished the connection but don't know the exact reason. Does it relate to HTTP2. Do we have some place to see the exact reason?

Below is the pcap snapshot.

[pcap snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQW9a.jpg)

---

Update 2017-07-30
Debug Log:

```html
Sun Jul 30, 2017 8:31:35.591 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2FrameCodec parse
FINE: Rx [2]: connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={localhost/127.0.0.1:80}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:57802}}, frame=DataFrame {streamId=277, type=0, flags=[none], length=42, data=BuffersBuffer (154351355) [pos=0 lim=42 cap=42 bufferSize=1 buffers=[HeapBuffer (165674143) [pos=0 lim=42 cap=8391], null, null, null]]}
Sun Jul 30, 2017 8:31:35.673 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2BaseFilter processFrames
FINE: Http2ConnectionException occurred on connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={localhost/127.0.0.1:80}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:57802}} during Http2Frame processing
Sun Jul 30, 2017 8:31:35.684 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2FrameCodec serializeAndRecycle
FINE: Tx: connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={localhost/127.0.0.1:80}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:57802}}, frame=GoAwayFrame {streamId=0, type=7, flags=[none], length=64{lastStreamId=199, errorCode=REFUSED_STREAM}
```

And the stream 277 in pcap snapshot

[pcap contains stream 277 from No 270,271 and 272](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufAXm.png)

There is a SETTINGS packet in 269 packet. Is it normal in the middle of the transportation to send SETTINGS? And after 269, there has three packets 270,271 and 272 are using steam 277.

Its strange that around 8:31:35.684 I didn't found GOWAY packet. But only in 8:31:36.035 RST/ACK is sent. At the round time the debug log is as below:

```html
Sun Jul 30, 2017 8:31:36.020 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2FrameCodec parse
FINE: Rx [2]: connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={localhost/127.0.0.1:80}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:57802}}, frame=DataFrame {streamId=465, type=0, flags=[END_STREAM], length=0, data=ByteBufferWrapper (1101850112) [visible=[java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]]]}
Sun Jul 30, 2017 8:31:36.023 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2BaseFilter processDataFrame
FINE: Data frame received for non-existent stream: connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={localhost/127.0.0.1:80}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:57802}}, frame=DataFrame {streamId=277, type=0, flags=[END_STREAM], length=0, data=ByteBufferWrapper (1101850112) [visible=[java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]]]}, stream=277
Sun Jul 30, 2017 8:31:36.024 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2BaseFilter processFrames
FINE: Http2StreamException occurred on connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={localhost/127.0.0.1:80}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:57802}} during Http2Frame processing
Sun Jul 30, 2017 8:31:36.025 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2BaseFilter processFrames
FINE: Http2ConnectionException occurred on connection=TCPNIOConnection{localSocketAddress={localhost/127.0.0.1:80}, peerSocketAddress={/127.0.0.1:57802}} during Http2Frame processing
```

The log showed received a non-existent stream 277. This stream is exactly the stream logged in the first log. Not sure this steam 277 cause RST/ACK in next several mili-second. I think it should have some problem with packet 269~272 and stream 277.

BTW, this time there has no FIN/ACK.

Comment: Log line at 8:31:35.591 seems to indicate that the `HEADERS` frame was somehow parsed for stream 277, but apparently did not succeed, causing the `GOAWAY`. Have you tried `FINEST` logging level ? Perhaps it has more indication of what went wrong. Also, have you tried another implementation such as Jetty HTTP/2 (disclaimer, I am the Jetty HTTP/2 maintainer) ?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to inject and configure Jetty HTTP/2 on Jersey. I can just only find very limited HTTP/2 container usage on Jersey. Appreciated if you can supply more info on this. Thanks.

Comment: I have set the log to FINEST, looks the same, process error then send GoAwayFrame. And at the pcap, RST/ACK is sent at last. But another strange thing I noticed in today's pcap and also I found in Yesterday's pcap. The server yield  didn't response until sending RST/ACK and also the response is a big one, but not including all expected responses. Yesterday's pcap even didn't has any response except a RST/ACK packet to the client.

Comment: @sbordet It looks this issue is related to the behavior of client and server,  when I increase the request number to 1000 (wait 5ms for each request), then only client sending requests but no response from the server until RST. But when I decrease the request number to 100, then the client and server ping-pang often and no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `pcap` shows an abnormal termination on the server.

You should check the server logs for more details of why that happened.

One possible cause is a server bug.

Another possible cause is that the client sent an invalid `HEADERS` frame at packet 14; still, the server should send a `GOAWAY` frame, not just closing the connection.

The `RST` at packet 17 is normal, since the client sent a `HEADERS` frame at packet 16 before processing the `FIN`, so the server replies with a `RST` indicating that the data sent did not make it to the user code layer.

The server logs (perhaps at DEBUG level) should tell you more about what happened.

Comment: I will try it and back to you later.

Comment: I have updated with debug log and some finding. Could you help to look at. Thanks.